# An Android Studio option has disappeared

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I updated my Android Studio and one of the options disappeared, which is textAlignment.  Where can I find it?

[image]

Comment: Just for a frame of reference, should someone read your question in the future, you should add the Android Studio version you updated from and to.

Answer (score 0):

Click on View All Attributes below. 
[image]

Comment: So I went there and searched and did not have that option.

Comment: it has to be there. Go all the way down. Its also alphabetically arranged. Also that widget should support text to have textAlignment attribute